# Using WinAmp to put music on an iPod/iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipod, winamp

Back in the day, with older iPods, you could copy music onto them using Winamp's Music Library. I heard that newer iPods and iPhones have all sort of encryption that prevents this from being fully functional. I'm looking to buy a new iPod soon, and would really like to avoid installing (or at least keeping) a copy of iTunes on my PC.

Are solutions still available through WinAmp? Other software? What iPod/iPhone models would work better?

Comment: if you don't like being coaxed into DRM and iTunes, then don't buy it. choices are plenty, in terms of quality AND freedom.

Comment: True, you might have better luck with a different product if you dont want to use itunes. Creative and many other companies make decent music players.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at **[Floola](http://www.floola.com/modules/wiwimod/)**.

works with any iPod except Touch

Comment: Works like a charm with my iPod and no iTunes installed on my office pc

Answer (score 1):

there used to be a plugin for winamp called ml_sync or something like that which used to work with iPhone/iTouch till OS versions 2.x but with 3.x it doesnt work anymore..

However you can look at some other tools like musicmonkey which can help you synch music with your PC..

there are a few other freeware programs too.. but i would have to look up the names for you.. i would update the list in a few days here..

Answer (score 0):

I found this article about [using Winamp to manage your iPod](http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/07/07/how-to-use-winamp-to-manage-your-ipod/). It's from 2007 so I don't know how relevant it is to the current generation of iPods.

Then there's the more recent [mlipod](http://www.mlipod.com/).

Comment: That's ml_ipod. It works great if your iPod is supported. iPhone/iTouch are not, but most other iPods are.